# Windows WMI: How to detect fixed disk drive is virtual

Tags: c#, c++, vbscript, wmi

By virtual I mean created using the SUBST cmd
eg SUBST Z: C:\SomeFolder\OtherFldr

Best method I can find in WMI is using the fact that a virtual drive will not have an association with a partition.

ie while:

```
ASSOCIATORS OF {Win32_LogicalDisk.DeviceID='C:'} 
WHERE AssocClass=Win32_LogicalDiskToPartition
```

will return the relevant `Win32_DiskPartition` row for `C:`

```
ASSOCIATORS OF {Win32_LogicalDisk.DeviceID='Z:'} 
WHERE AssocClass=Win32_LogicalDiskToPartition"
```

will return nothing.

Does anyone know a better way?

My project is in C++, but suggestions in C#, VBS, PowerShell welcome as the principal is usually the same.

Comment: Does it _have_ to be WMI? You can use `QueryDosDevice` (https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa365461(v=vs.85).aspx)

Comment: Does not have to be WMI. Am collecting a set of info for each disk where WMI supplies everything I need. While what I have works to detect disk as  virtual have feeling there should be a more direct way eg some column in some table that I have over looked.

Answer (score 0):

Looks like a job for `GetVolumeNameForVolumeMountPoint`. In your example `Z:` is not a volume mount point.